# Parsing/edition docx file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xquery

I've been asked to write a php script that should read/parse a docx file and do some operations such as duplicate a specific paragraph/table and fill-in some variables (#myvar or $myvar) with values.
What do you guys recommand, use the word/document.xml file directly or convert the whole document to an HTML file and then parse it using DOM(I don't like this solution :(  )?
the structure of the docx to parse is not defined yet, it's my job to do that ! And it has to be as general as possible.

To have a clear idea about what I'm doing, the docx file is a CV model that I have to fill-in with data from DB.
P.S: I don't know how to efficiently parse/modify the XML file using Xquery since the only solution I have is to use variables (plain text with $ or #..) inside that docx
thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you looked at PHPWord?

Comment: Replace the variables in the xml directly, then offer the modified docx for download?

Comment: But can I extract nodes with xquery and do some processing with it? duplicate, delete etc.?
I've tried that using simple DOM API bundled with PHP and I got a corrupted docx file that MS Word couldn't read :(

@Mark Baker: with PHPWord, you creat a docx from scratch and I want to work on an existing docx file
Maerlyn : yes, but not only that, I want to play with the word/document.xml nodes as well(copy, paste, delete)

Thanks guys for your replies

Comment: no xquery support in PHP but xpath. And DOMDocument has replace node, clone node and remove child. So everything you need for dom manipulation. However if you screw the file, there is nothing we can help you with that. Don't screw it :) - If you add more code and provide some data - with more context there might be more help.

Comment: 1)I've already tried DOMDocument with php and the problem is that if I modify the initial nodes structure of the word/document.xml, the result file is corrupted and can't be opened with MS word

Comment: 2)If I convert docx to html, the html file is invalid and can't be parsed with dom neither as html nor as xml. @hakre: here is the context of my application: the administrator submits a docx file which is a model used to generate CV docx. It should contain some information about the style used for each element(paragraph, lists etc.) and can also contain some variables such as $fullname$, $poste$ etc. The user can fill in a dynamic form that contains sections, paragraphs etc. and then he can choose a model and generate the docx file

Comment: For 1.) Don't corrupt it. Sure you can break it, so don't break it with DOM manipulation, only manipulate what does not break the format. 2.) Which kind of invalidity? And also PHP can repair invalid HTML documents with the Tidy extension as well as DOMDocument can load HTML and also recover it. So there are many options you still have. 3.) Start with something easy, e.g. first of all just try to open a DOCX do some allowed modification (start with something really simple, e.g. select a headline element and add some text inside or similar), save again and see it works. When it does, step on.

Comment: @hakre I can add/modify text, the problem is with nodes! the document.xml can only be read by MS Word, it contains some ids that MS word can generate and interpret.What I want to do is to duplicate some nodes (let's say tr) and because each node has its own id, duplication is not allowed. Anyway, I tried working on the HTML file generated by MS word but the problem is that the function DOMDocument::saveXML() eliminates some tags that only MS Word can understand;

Comment: it does some clean up somehow and I don't know why since the navigator can read the HTML file without errors whereas the PHP DOM API fires a lot of warnings when I try to parse this file.

Comment: @fadelo: By default DOMDocument does not remove stuff with saveXML. You might look if there are some libxml options that might be having a side-effect, e.g. entitiy subsitutions or what not. Also you need to create some example code + data to demonstrate your issue otherwise it's only guessing around which does not really brings you forward.

Comment: @hakre: thanks for your reply, I appreciate it a lot! well, may be I didn't explain it very clearly but what I'm doing is that I manualy save the docx file as HTML and then opperate on it. The problem is that when I call saveXML() or save() or saveHTML(), the document is modified. Here is what I do : I call $dom_document->loadHTML(file_get_contents("MyDoc.htm")); and then $dom_document->save("MyDoc2.htm"); MyDoc.htm and MyDoc2.htm are different indeed! I use DiffMerge to compare the 2 documents since they are huge.How can I post the 2 files here(if you're interested) ?

Comment: But why don't you modify the DOCX file directly? It is XML, just inside a ZIP file.

Comment: When I tried to manipulate the word/document.docx directly (adding nodes etc.) the file got corrupted and MSWord couldn't read it!! I've been told that it's hard to manipulate an existing docx file since MSWord is the only program that can deal with those generated ids.To be more specific, what I did  with that XML file is that I duplicated some nodes and since they got identical ids the docx got damaged

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 major PHP libraries able to create Word documents. Here's a description of features from both that might help you solve your problem:

1. [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) (opensource) - allows to load template documents and replace values... take a look at this [example in library's source code](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/Examples/Template.php), maybe you can define a CV template and use this to work a solution out;
2. [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com/) (free with basic features, paid for more advanced features) - allows templates and search and replace of content in documents (probably only in paid versions though).

Comment: Thanks @Rolando for your answer but PHPWord is really limited.What I've been asked to do with the template is more than replacing keys by values, but duplicating some elements(tables, paragraphs,etc.).The only solution I've got is to work on the HTML generated from the template instead. If someone can help me how to convert docx to html and then from html to docx I'll apreciate it a lot. So far, I've found some interesting APIs but they are for c#

Answer (score 1):

This is a old question, but I thought I give some pointers as I have been struggling with this for some time and have ended up writing my own package at [github: wrklst/docxmustache](https://github.com/wrklst/docxmustache).

Here are some solutions I know of:

Free solutions:

- https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord (as mentioned above, cumbersome and not very capable)
- http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php (works but is highly cumbersome, also introduces a lot of security issues if you plan to allow user supplied templates)

Partially Free and Paid:

- https://www.phpdocx.com
- http://www.docxpresso.com (looks like one of the more complete solutions to me, at 199 eur for a server license its not too expensive either)
- https://modules.docxtemplater.com

I worked with opentbs quite a bit but I am not happy with it and I am currently trying to evaluate to write my own solution that is more geared to my specific needs. Generally you need:
- A zip calss to unzip/rezip the docx file
- A template engine to replace values, I am using mustache (https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php)
- If you are planning to replace images as well you need to more advanced file, reference and xml handling. Php's SimpleXMLElement should be sufficient to handle all the xml manipulation.

Off course you can always convert the docx into a more accessible format, but that will greatly mess with any styling. If thats not an issue I recommend to use libreoffice to convert your docx into any format that libreoffice supports. on linux based servers you can easily access it via command line, here an example with symfony for command execution:

```
$command = "soffice --headless --convert-to html ".$inputfile.' --outdir '.$outputfile.'/');
            $process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process($command);
            $process->start();
            while ($process->isRunning()) {}
            // executes after the command finishes
            if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                throw new \Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException($process);
            }
```

Check out my [package wrklst/docxmustache](https://github.com/wrklst/docxmustache) if you want to see this in context.

good luck!