# Parsing docx with encoding in php

Tags: php, parsing

Okay, so I have a docx file full of text (only text) and I wanna parse it in a  very specific way. Keep in mind that it's using special characters from Serbian Latin such as ŠĐŽĆČ

Here's what I'm trying to do:
1) Take each word from the text, ignoring 1 letter words
2) If it's encoded with special characters (eg Čovek) make two versions of it, one being "Čovek" and another being "Covek" (so one with special chars and one without) 
3) Save both in a table under the appropriate column (determined by the first letter of the word, so C for Covek and Č for Čovek. This is only if they don't already exist, if they do skip

That's it. Files exist, table structure exists, I just have no idea how to parse them.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105818/parsing-edition-docx-file-with-php, there are a few options suggested there.

Comment: It's possible, however, that one considers parsing a docx file. Maybe I haven't described my problem quite well, so here goes:

1) I take a pdf and do OCR with Abby FineReader, so I can have any output (doc, docs, txt) with the special characters.
2) I don't know how to parse text word by word
3) I don't know how to handle encoding, to create 2 words from 1 where necessary
4) I don't know how to insert them under the appropriate column in the table
5) I have an idea how to check if the word already exists

Hope that helped!